# PostgreSQL date C# DateTime

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime, insert

I'm using this query to insert into a table a date:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String query = "Insert into \"Table1\" (\"tableDate\") values (:date1)";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conex.getConnection());
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
NpgsqlParameter param = new NpgsqlParameter(":date1",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date);
param.Value = dt.ToShortDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add(param); // <----------Here i get the error
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

And this is how I am inserting in the table any other value and it works! So there must be an error in the date format or something, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do

```
param.Value = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

leave just

```
param.Value = dt;
```

You're trying to insert a string into DateTime field - sure PostgreSQL will complain.

use NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp if you want to avoid losing the time information

Comment: But im doing the same with a lot of other datatype... let me try

Comment: I love u!! thx for the help!!! omg!! i couldnt find the answer anywhere! if i could ill give u a million points for that!