# How to set DateTime.Now when inserting in postgresql table?

Tags: c#, postgresql

We ship images and the default culture setting for our image is MDY.

The customer server where the image is installed has a locale of DMY has been using our image for a few days and then noticed datestyle errors with dates (i.e.  when inserting a DateTime.Now() into a table).

We have tried changing the postgreSQL  locale to DMY (in postgresql.conf) but with no luck.

I was thinking about converting all DateTime.Now() calls in my C# app to DMY format.

I also noticed that I could set   in my web.config which may help.

As I cannot seem to change the postgreSQL settings what are my options?

Another option I was thinking was to uninstall postgreSQL  and then install it again with the correct locale set (as long as I backup up my database). Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476476/postgresql-date-c-sharp-datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need to insert current time send the value as `now`

```
   INSERT INTO TestTable (code, title,  date)
        VALUES ('aaa', 'bbbb', now);
```

you can use parameters for other columns, let server insert the current date time value from database side

if you going to set datetime parameter, don't set value as string.  do as below

```
string sql  ="INSERT INTO TestTable (dateTimeColumnName) VALUES (:datetimeParamName)";
// create connection cmd etc...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":datetimeParamName", DateTime.Now);
```

OR

```
NpgsqlParameter param = new NpgsqlParameter(":datetimeParamName",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date);
param.Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Thanks Damith. I see that in code I am creating an SQL string passing in DateTime.Now and the that is passed to a DbCommand (ServiceStack) executeSQL() method. I will try var sql ="INSERT INTO TestTable (dateTimeColumnName) VALUES (now)" to see if that works otherwise I will go with your last approach.