# how to convert string Npgsqldate in EF Core

Tags: c#

i have stuck in converting string to Npgsql

```
String dtTo="2020/07/01"

NpgsqlDate DateTo = NpgsqlDate.ToNpgsqlDate(Convert.ToDateTime(dtTo));
```

it gives me an error which  says No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'NpgsqlDate'

i need it for my stored procedure :

```
regionalManager = "%";
        dtFrom = "2020-07-03";
        dtTo = "2020-07-07";
        string service_under = "%";
        string supervisor = "%";


        NpgsqlDate DateFrom = NpgsqlDate.Parse(dtFrom);
        NpgsqlDate DateTo = NpgsqlDate.Parse(dtTo);
        NpgsqlParameter p0 = new NpgsqlParameter("@drfrom", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
        NpgsqlParameter p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtto", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
        NpgsqlParameter p2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@regionalmanager", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p3 = new NpgsqlParameter("@serviceunder", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p4 = new NpgsqlParameter("@supervisor", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
    
        var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)",DateFrom,DateTo,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor
                          ).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you using parameters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476476/postgresql-date-c-sharp-datetime

Comment: @jdweng i have updated my question

Comment: @jdweng dont know how can i pass the date which is string to my SP

Comment: DateTo and DateFrom should also be parameters.

Comment: do not convert . just send yyyy/mm/dd string format

Comment: @LDS in DB its expecting date format

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean?

Comment: Last Line of query doe snot have any parameters : ,@p5, @p6,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor

Comment: @jdweng updated my question ,the strange thing is when i directly pass string format as a date to my function it works but as a parameter it does not work

Comment: Is database a string or a datetime?

Comment: @jdweng its date

Comment: Did you create parameters @p5 and @p6?

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by p5 and p6 i have 4 params :)

Comment: I think you need new SqlParameter("@searchTerm", userSuppliedSearchTerm) [See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1]  You have instead : DateFrom,DateTo,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor