# C#- "DateTime.UtcNow" outputs date in a format which is treated as out of range for Postgres DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, datetime

I have shifted to a new laptop (windows 10 i5) and trying to set up my .NET app. I am encountering a weird problem and it has taken a whole lot of my time. In my app, I am storing the current date-time in UTC format in a Postgres DB table. The c# command `DateTime.UtcNow` outputs the date format as

> 14-12-2021 13:50:57

When the above date is passed via an insert query to be stored in the Postgres Db, it throws the error as

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "14-12-2021 13:50:57"

What seems even stranger is, that on my old laptop (same OS - windows 10 i3), the same code works fine and gives the output of the date as

> 12/14/2021 07:24:24 AM

and this format is accepted by the Postgres DB.

The table design is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Log"
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Log_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "QueueId" uuid NOT NULL,
    "MessageId" character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "LogTime" timestamp without time zone,   
   
    CONSTRAINT "Log_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
```

The Value resulting from the `DateTime.UtcNow` is being passed into the `LogTime` column.

Here is the, c# code that forms the Postgres query.

```
string query = $@"INSERT INTO public.""Log""(
                            ""QueueId"", 
                            ""LogTime"", 
                            ""Message"", 
                            )
                            VALUES(
                            '{req.QueueId}', 
                            '{req.LogTime}', 
                            '{(item.Message.Length > 100 ? item.Message.Substring(0, 100) : item.Message)}'                           
                            RETURNING ""Id"";";
```

The same code behaves differently on different machines with the same OS. Any clues would be extremely appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing dates with any format and using date/time types on those columns in the database

Comment: How do you pass this value to your db? Are you directly or indirectly transforming a datetime variable in a string and then ask the db to transform it back to a datetime? Please add the relevant code where you have the insertion logic

Comment: I am not doing any transformations. Just passing the "Datetime.Now" as a value for a timestamp datatype of Postgres. This is very much working on my old laptop.

Comment: Postgresql has different [date/time data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html). Choose one of them instead of string

Comment: @KlausGütter please watch my comment just above yours. I am not doing any transformations

Comment: Please show what you are doing exactly

Comment: This is almost certainly a serialization problem (as mentioned in other comments). Could you include the table design and the code that writes to the table in your question?

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: @KlausGütter, included the table design and an additional comment with my edits

Comment: Thank you, and how does the C# code look like where you add the row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL date C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476476/postgresql-date-c-sharp-datetime)

Comment: @KlausGütter added the c# code that forms the query and the column being talked about is "Logtime"

Comment: I'd say this is almost certainly a localisation problem, if your code works with 12-12 but not 14-12 or 12-14 then the date is being parsed incorrectly. Perhaps when you reinstalled the machine you selected English UK instead of English US or vica versa.

Comment: @NibblyPig, Sure thanks for a different view to the problem. I have tried a lot to match the datetime formats between my old and new laptop in the Control Panel Settings, and I guess I have brought that exactly to the same values, but still doesnt work.

Comment: You are transforming a datetime in a string when you write _'{req.LogTime}',_ and createing a new whole can of worms with code open to Sql Injection. You should use parameters to pass values to your database. But just looking at the string conversion problem. The implicit ToString in your code applies a formatting to your date value then your database needs to transform it back to a date and obviously the format received is not correctly accepted by the localization of your server machine.

Comment: @Steve, thanks much for your comments. Will definitely address them. Can you tell me where exactly can I change the localization settings of my laptop? So that I can match it with the settings on my old laptop

Comment: Probably in the Settings then in the Date/Time and finally in the Geographical Area (not sure about the names because I don't have installed an English OS). But why you want to do this? Fix the problem in a definitive way using parameters. You just need to add three lines of code

Comment: @puneet this has nothing to do with locales and settings, it's a bug in your code and database. `DateTime` is a binary value, it has no format. Almost all databases (except SQLite) have date types, which also have no format. *Your code* converts the binary date value into a string and stores the string. Fix that. BTW your code is wide open to SQL injection as well. Imagine what would happen if `msg` contained `'); drop table users; --'`

Comment: @NibblyPig this isn't a serialization issue. Thinking this has anything to do with formats or locales is the actual problem hiding the actual problem *and* a critical security vulnerability

Answer (score 4):

I repeat my comment above because you are transforming a datetime in a string when you write '{req.LogTime}', and with that the code creates a parsing problem for your database because it needs to translate that string back to a timespan to insert it in the column. Not only this is prone to different result when converting the strings (one pc thinks that the right format for a date is "MM-dd", the other one thinks of "dd-MM") but it is also creates a well known vulnerability called Sql Injection.
You should simply use parameters to pass values to your database.
With a proper type defined parameter there is no more ambiguity in the resolution of the value and the database is not affected by script kids trying the easiest hack in the world.

```
string query = $@"INSERT INTO public.""Log""(
                  ""QueueId"", LogTime"", ""Message"")
                  VALUES(@qid, @ltime, @msg)                           
                  RETURNING ""Id"";";

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qid", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid).Value = req.QueueId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ltime", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = req.LogTime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = 
         (item.Message.Length > 100 ? item.Message.Substring(0, 100) : item.Message);
   var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Writing  correct code in this case is simpler than writing bad code. And if one uses Dapper, this becomes 4 lines, including the query

Comment: @Steve, I can understand your point. Please understand that this is a POC and NOT a production code. Before it becomes a production code, all the relevant points will be sorted out. Right now, that is not a concern to me, as I said that the same code WORKS on a different laptop but not this one.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. I have explained what I think is the cause of the erratic behavior and how to fix it.

Comment: @Steve, I am aware that your solution will fix it anyway. But my point is not to get an answer to this situation, but the cause of the situation. The issue is, I am not sure why the same code behaves differently on 2 different machines.

Comment: I thought I have explained it in my answer. The client PC sends a date transformed in a string to your server. It asks the underlying ToString() to format that date into a string but this transform happens in the client PC with its rules about date representation. The server is unable to make that string back to a date because it has a different understanding of how a string representing a date should be written.